# NodeJS refresh token without Redis/DB

Tags: node.js, jwt

As I understand there are 3 approaches to tokens and their expiry time. During development I've use tokens that do not expire, but before production need something a little better but not necessarily something that will take forever to implement. I'm using NodeJS with jsonwebtoken to deliver to mobile clients.

The options:

1. A token that does not expire, leaving your App open to miscreant behaviour.
2. Use Redis and refresh tokens. Once a token expires, use a refresh token to generate a new token. The refresh token has a long expiration, and must be stored safely on the client side.
3. Everytime a call is made with a short-lived token, provide a new token with an arbitrary expiry (15 minutes). The client uses the new token for each request.

Why is the third option not a valid approach?

Comment: The issue with #3 is that you'd be able to keep an access token alive forever.  https://auth0.com has some fantastic documentation on best practices with tokens, and I would highly recommend reading some of their posts.  #2 is by far the best approach listed, but generally you don't need a database (Redis) to validate the access token, just a method to decrypt the token claims.  That is one of the reasons for keeping the access token lifetime short

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using a fourth option:

- create a refresh token with jwt and longer expiration date than the access token. so the payloads look like this:

access-token:

```
{ type: "access-token", sub: "<userid>", exp: "<1 day>" }
```

refresh-token:

```
{ type: "refresh-token", sub: "<userid>", exp: "<1 year>" }
```

now you do not need to store refresh-token in redis or any other storage system as the owner of the token is in payload and the validity of token can be checked using jwt.

as for your third option, it is not a good idea because if user doesn't use your system for 15 minutes, he will have to login again.

Comment: Be gentle with me, but I can't see the advantage of having a refresh token in this case (as it's not implemented in node-jsonwebtoken), meaning that the refesh and access token would be the same. In that case, isn't it just the same as creating an access token with 1 year validity?

Comment: the access token is only used to authorize/authenticate api calls while the refresh token is used to generate new access tokens. so when the user needs to create a new access token without logging in again he should provide the refresh token to a specific endpoint to get new access token and use that on other apis. this flow is the same as OAuth2 refresh_token grant_type flow.
also keep in mind that you cant use refresh_token instead of access_token. so in your authenticate function you should check the payload "type" option to make sure the token is of access token type.

Comment: But if you can't invalidate the refresh token than it can be used by a bad actor to create auth tokens at any time. Doesn't see right to me.

Comment: yes that is the downside of this option. maybe reducing refresh token expiration date help, but at the end it is a compromise decision to make.